# Displaying nested array values in table with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, spring

I'm using Spring MVC and AngularJS in my application and in a particular table I have to display inside the same `<td>` multiple values from an array but I don´t know how. Anyway this will explain it better:

```html
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
       <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Acciones</th>
              <th>Referencia</th>
              <th>Tipo de Publicaci&oacute;n</th>
              <th>Categor&iacute;a</th>
              <th>Fecha de adici&oacute;n</th>
              <th>Fecha de modificaci&oacute;n</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr data-ng-repeat="referencia in allReferencias track by $index">
              <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="abrirEditarModal($index)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#informe">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModalEliminar" data-ng-click="abrirEliminarModal($index)">
                       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
              </td>
              <td>{{referencia.autoresList}},({{referencia.fecha}}). {{referencia.title}}, {{referencia.location}}, {{referencia.arcPublication}}, 
{{referencia.volumen}}({{referencia.numVol}}),{{referencia.pages}}</td>
              <td>{{referencia.idFuente.nombreFuente}}</td>
              <td>{{referencia.idGrupo.grupo}}</td>
              <td>{{referencia.fechaAd| date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
              <td>{{referencia.fechaMod| date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

What I get from the server is

[image: Server result]

and inside every record there is other array:

[image: Array in record]

And I all I need to display from `autoresList` is the `nombres` and `apellidos` attributes. So that is my question how can I display those two attributes in the same `<td>`?

Comment: Could you please stringify and post your JSON response

Comment: thanks for answering!! but I dont know how to do that stringify...anyway i tried the answer below and work so, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `<td>` code by this

```
<td>
  <span data-ng-repeat="autoRes in referencia.autoresList">
    {{autoRes.nombre}},{{autoRes.apellidos}} 
  </span>, 
    ({{referencia.fecha}}). {{referencia.title}}, 
    {{referencia.location}}, 
    {{referencia.arcPublication}}, 
    {{referencia.volumen}}({{referencia.numVol}}),{{referencia.pages}} 
</td>
```

Comment: THANKS!!! this work perflectly, thats what I needed, I didnt know that I could do a ng-repeat inside another

Comment: By the way, how could I just print the first letter of the "apellidos" properties instead of the whole "apellidos"??

Comment: Thanks for your response use limit to filter like this way {{autoRes.apellidos | limitTo:1}}

Comment: oh I already vote up, but since i don´t have 15 reputation yet, it doesn't gets displayed, but I did marked the answer as accepted